# Reduce three lines of arithmetic to one line? Divide and round

Tags: php, math, arithmetic-expressions

I have an integer value which will always be a whole number, called `$post_count`

I want to divide `$post_count` by 2. So if it's an even number, it will always produce a whole result. E.g if `$post_count = 8` then I want the result of my arithmetic to be `4`.

However if it's an odd number, I wish to presented with the rounded-up number. So if `$post_count = 7`, I would still want the answer to be `4`, because the maths is =

```
7 / 2 = 3.5
3.5 rounded up = 4
```

I've written the following code but I am wondering if it's possible to reduce this quite lengthy code into something simpler?

```
$post_count = $the_query->found_posts;
$post_count = $post_count / 2;
$post_count = round($post_count);
```

Comment: `$post_count = round($the_query->found_posts/2);`

Comment: You can write combination of all 3 line in one: `$post_count = round($the_query->found_posts / 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ceil` -

```
$post_count = ceil( $the_query->found_posts / 2 );
```

If `$the_query->found_posts = 7` then it will print `4`. `ceil` will always return the next bigger integer of the current number.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$posts = 7;
echo round($posts/2);
// 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$post_count = round($the_query->found_posts/2);
```